# Missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : client_secret

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am using [p2.OAuth2](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2) library for Oauth2 access to Linkedin. As mentioned in the [usage section](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2/blob/master/README.md#usage), I have created the following code for getting access token.

```
  let settingsLinkedin = [
        "client_id": "75afkn125135v14",
        "client_secret": "R5gHlmkRtld4xge4",
        "authorize_uri": "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization",
        "token_uri": "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken",
        "scope": "",
        "redirect_uris": ["http://www.dummyredirecturl.com/oauth.aspx"],   // don't forget to register this scheme
        "keychain": false        ] as OAuth2JSON            // the "as" part may or may not be needed


        let oauth2 = OAuth2CodeGrant(settings: settingsLinkedin)
        oauth2.onAuthorize = { parameters in
            println("Did authorize with parameters: \(parameters)")
        }
        oauth2.onFailure = { error in        // `error` is nil on cancel
            if nil != error {
                println("Authorization went wrong: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }


        oauth2.authConfig.authorizeEmbedded = true
        oauth2.authConfig.authorizeContext = self.view.window!.rootViewController
        //oauth2.authConfig.ui.backButton = <# UIBarButtonItem(...) #>    // to customize go-back button
        oauth2.authorize()
```

The problem is that when I use it with Linkedin, it gives following error:

> Authorization went wrong: missing required parameters, includes an
>   invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : client_secret

When I use [implicit-grant](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2/blob/master/README.md#implicit-grant), I get following error, even before the user credentials form comes up:

> Authorization went wrong: Invalid redirect URL:
>   http://www.dummyredirecturl.com/oauth.aspx?error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=We+only+support+a+response_type+of+%22code%22%2C+but+you+passed+token

Also, when I use the above code for Facebook (of-course after changing credentials) , it works correctly.

Comment: did you fond any solution for this? please post it, it would be helpful